# Laravel EXCEL and PDF export

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, export, export-to-excel, export-to-pdf

I am new in Laravel and I am using Laravel 4.2

I like to export some data in PDF and excel.

Is there any way in Laravel?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) to do what u need. You must create a pdf file from scratch and fill it in the way u want.

```
<?php
require('fpdf.php');

$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();    // add page to PDF
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);    // Choose a font and size
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');  // write anything to any line you want
$pdf->Output("your_name.pdf");   // Export the file and send in to browser       
?>
```

And for Excel a simple way is to add [PHPExcel](http://www.sitepoint.com/generate-excel-files-charts-phpexcel/) to laravel. Add this line to your `composer.json`:

```
"require": {
    "phpexcel/phpexcel": "dev-master"
}
```

then run a `composer update`. So use it like this:

```
$ea = new PHPExcel();

$ea->getProperties()
   ->setCreator('somebody')
   ->setTitle('PHPExcel Demo')
   ->setLastModifiedBy('soembody')
   ->setDescription('A demo to show how to use PHPExcel to manipulate an Excel file')
   ->setSubject('PHP Excel manipulation')
   ->setKeywords('excel php office phpexcel')
   ->setCategory('programming')
   ;

$ews = $ea->getSheet(0);
$ews->setTitle('Data');

$ews->setCellValue('a1', 'ID'); // Sets cell 'a1' to value 'ID 
$ews->setCellValue('b1', 'Season');
```

Comment: how do you export excel to PDF?

Comment: @Peyman.H If i use a jquery plugin like [this](https://developer.aliyun.com/mirror/npm/package/tableexport.jquery.plugin) for exporting to excel and pdf then are there any problems?. Can someone suggest me best professional jquery plugin for exporting to excel (xlsx) and pdf ??

Answer (score 4):

Use [maatwebsite](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs) to Create and import Excel, CSV and PDF files

Add this lines to your `composer.json`:

```
"require": {
   "maatwebsite/excel": "~2.1.0"
}
```

After updating composer, add the ServiceProvider to the providers array in config/app.php

```
Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider::class,
```

You can use the facade for shorter code. Add this to your aliasses:

```
'Excel' => Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel::class,
```

To publish the config settings in Laravel 5 use:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider"
```

simple use of this package:

```
    $users = User::select('id','name' ,'username')->get();
    $Info = array();
    array_push($Info, ['id','name' ,'username']);
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        array_push($Info, $user->toArray());
    }
    Excel::create('Users', function($excel) use ($Info) {

        $excel->setTitle('Users');
        $excel->setCreator('milad')->setCompany('Test');
        $excel->setDescription('users file'); 
        $excel->sheet('sheet1', function($sheet) use ($Info) {
            $sheet->setRightToLeft(true);
            $sheet->fromArray($Info, null, 'A1', false, false);
        });

    })->download('xls'); // or download('PDF')
```